# jQuery get value or text of clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hyperlink

I have a select menu where users select a category and then they select a business from that category. Each business is a li and a tag. Once the user select the business link a table is suppose to appear. However, I can't get the table to appear because I can't grab the value or text of the link. Can someone help me get the value or text of a link once its clicked.

```js
function clickListingLink(businessLinkSelected) {
  // function is for when a link is clicked after list of businesses appear
  $('#listOfBusinesses').on('click', 'li', function() {
    seeListingInfoTable(businessLinkSelected);
    $("hr").show();
  });
}

function seeListingInfoTable(businessLinkSelected) {
  // function is for table that shows info of specific link clicked 
  var tbl = "";
  tbl += '<table class="table table-hover">';
  tbl += '<tbody>';
  tbl += '<caption class="listingTitle">' + titleOfBusinessSelected +
    '</caption>';
  tbl += '<tr>';
  tbl += '<th>Address</th>';
  tbl += '<th>Phone Number</th>';
  tbl += '<th>Website</th>';
  tbl += '<th>Specialty</th>';
  tbl += '</tr>';
  tbl += '<tr>';
  tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' +
    businessLinkSelected["Address"] + '</div></td>';
  tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname"> +
    businessLinkSelected["Phone Number"] + '</div></td>';
  tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' +
    businessLinkSelected["Website"] + '</div></td>';
  tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' +
    businessLinkSelected["Specialty"] + '</div></td>';
  tbl += '</tr>';
  tbl += '</tbody>';
  tbl += '</table>';
  $(document).find("#infoTable").html(tbl);
} // line ends seeListingInfoTable function
```

Also attached is a screenshot of how my project works so far. What you'll see in the image is the drop down select, then you'll see the list of options appear. This is where the user chooses a link and once they click on the link a table should appear with information about the selected business:

[image]

Comment: code shows clicking on an li and your html generates a table? where is the list? SO read the text? `$(this).text()`

Comment: No it's not generating a table. Once the user clicks on 1 of the 2 li links a table with info about that business is suppose to appear. It's not happening

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Sample:

```
$('#listOfBusinesses').on('click', 'li', function() {
   $("hr").show();
   var aTags = $(this).find( "a" ); // this returns all the a tags inside the clicked li as an array
   console.log(aTags[0].html());
});
```

Comment: Would I put this code in my "clickListingLink" function like this: function clickListingLink(businessLinkSelected) {
      // function is for when a link is clicked after list of businesses appear
      $('#listOfBusinesses').on('click','li', function(){
        $( "li" ).find( "a" ).html();
      seeListingInfoTable(businessLinkSelected); 
      $("hr").show();    
      });
    }

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please refer to it?

Comment: I just tried it and it's still not displaying a populated table with the clicked a info.